# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en PHP y mostrar ventanas Pop-Up en un sitio web?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, modal, hosting, popup

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web de una empresa que ofrece servicios de reparación y mantenimiento de cómputo. Una de las páginas del sitio debe de mostrar una ventana modal al presionar encima de un botón, y el usuario cliente debe escribir su número de orden en un input para saber si su equipo ya ha sido reparado mostrando ventanas Pop-Up. [image: Ventana modal]
Las ventanas Pop-Up están en html, he intentado hacer la conexión con el servidor de Hostinger que es en donde tengo almacenado el sitio y la base de datos que utilizaré, pero no me funciona ni la conexión ni el código php para hacer la búsqueda del dato en la base de datos. Mi base de datos solo tiene una tabla con dos columnas, una columna es el número de orden y en la otra columna se muestra con un 1 o 0 si la orden está lista o sigue en taller.

### Código de ventana modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade " id="demoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="demoModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered  " role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body py-sm-4 px-sm-5">
                      <button type="button" class="close " data-dismiss="modal"
                       aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                      <div class="text-center pt-5">
                        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/3067/3067416.png">
                          <h3>Consulta de orden</h3>
                            <p class="text-muted">
                              Consulta el estado del servicio que has solicitado ingresando tu número de orden asignado.
                            </p>
                      </div>
                      <form name="consulta" method="post" action="ejecutar.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Número de orden</label>
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" name="orden">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-cstm-dark btn-cta" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;">Enviar</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Modal Ends -->
```

No tengo idea en dónde deba de ir la programación php para que busque en la base de datos y dependiendo de la columna que indica si la orden está terminada o no mostrar un Pop-Up. He estado buscando por internet pero los códigos no me funcionan.

### Código de conectar.php

```
<?php
$servername = 127.0.0.1";
$database = "u950992049_Reparaciones";
$username = "u950992049_root";
$password = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el código que tienes en `ejecutar.php`. Ese es el archivo que te comunicará con el servidor (conexión a la base de datos, etc) cuando envíes el formulario. Cuando te funcione la conexión y obtengas los datos que se envían desde el `input` te va a convenir usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, para mostrar el popup sin recargar la página.

Comment: Ya lo mostré, cuando lo ejecuto me manda error al conectar con el servidor.

Comment: ¿No le faltan las comillas iniciales a `127.0.0.1`?